# How to add special characters to xml tag using lxml?

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

I am trying to create xml file using lxml as below

```
from lxml import etree
var = "xyz"
root = etree.Element("Demo_root")
a = etree.SubElement(root, "Demo2='"+var+"'")
```

getting error as

> invalid tag  name

at line number 4 in the code, I can't able to give any special characters. So how can i handle it.

My file should be look as

```
<x Name="dem1">
  <y Name="dem2" Value="1"/>
  <y Name="dem3" Value="2"/>        
</x>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Any way to do what? Please read https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html

Comment: Are you trying to add an attribute instead of creating an element? Please add an example of what the XML should look like.

Comment: @DanielHaley i have edited my question, now you may get clear idea about how it looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is create an attribute and not a child element. (It's still hard to tell since the element/attribute names in your XML don't match what's in your code.)

To create an attribute, you can use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set).

Example to create the XML in your example...

```py
from lxml import etree

var = "dem1"  # A variable isn't needed, but I included it anyway since your original code had it.

root = etree.Element("x")
root.set("Name", var)

for x in range(1, 3):
    elem = etree.Element("y")
    elem.set("Name", "dem{}".format(x + 1))
    elem.set("Value", str(x))
    root.append(elem)

etree.dump(root)
```

Output...

```xml
<x Name="dem1">
  <y Name="dem2" Value="1"/>
  <y Name="dem3" Value="2"/>
</x>
```